# PyDev Sync System PYTHONPATH results in Python crashing

Tags: eclipse, crash, pydev

I'm running PyDev 6.4.1.2 on Eclipse EE Neon (4.6.3) on OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan)

Whenever I update the PYTHONPATH and syncing is attempted, I get 3 warnings that Python has crashed. The updated PYTHONPATH still works, but I was wondering what the possible cause of this could be.

Thank you.

[image: Error Log]

Answer (score 0):

The reason it crashes is because when doing `some_module = __import__("some.module")`, `dir(some_module)`, that module is crashing and usually means an error in compilation of such module or some wrong environment variable (so, the module is not being properly initialized).

I'm not sure PyDev prints which module was the culprit... do you have some error in your error log after the crash happens?

http://www.pydev.org/faq.html#HowdoIReportaBUG has instructions on finding the error log.

Comment: I've uploaded the screenshot in the original post. Let me know if you'd like the full error log.